# Increment margin using jquery

Tags: css, positioning, margin

I have a set of images that i want to place in a stair type way, like so:

`img
   img
      img 
         img`

I want the images to overlap and I'm currently using faux positioning. 
You can see an example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2PSFC/

I would like to add a margin-top and margin-left of 40px to every img after the first one. As you can see the :nth-child doesn't seem to be working, but anyways i would much prefer adding the margin with jquery. any ideas?

Comment: Please include the code that you have on jsFiddle so that others may learn from your question in the future, or when jsFiddle is down.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the number of images, you can set the margins dynamically using jQuery:

```
$('.stuff').css('margin-top', function(i) { return i * 40; })
           .css('margin-left', function(i) { return i * 40; });
```

Or

```
$('.stuff').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({ 'margin-top': i * 40, 'margin-left': i * 40 }); 
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PSFC/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you think there would be a way to center the stack within a wrapper?

Comment: @DimitraZuccarelli The entire set of divs is being rather uncooperative in jsFiddle because the .wrapper div wants to be 100% of the page width no matter what I tell it. I'll mess around with it a bit more before I post what I have.

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't too many elements, I wouldn't suggest using jQuery. To fix your CSS do this:

```
.container:nth-child(2) .stuff { margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 40px; }
```

Since every element with the class .stuff is wrapped in a container div, it will be the first and only child, but the container divs have different child indexes.

jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/WKE4n/

Comment: Here's a working jsfiddle without any javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/2PSFC/4/

Answer (score 0):

Including an answer for centering the stack of images in the parent element, which was asked as a comment on another answer:

```
$('.stuff')
  .css('margin-top', function(i) { return i * 40; })
  .css('margin-left', function(i) { return i * 40; });
$('.wrapper').css('left',($('.wrapper').parent().width() / 2) - ($('.stuff').length * 20) - ($('.stuff').width() / 2));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PSFC/14/)

I'm sure there's some way to clean up that second "line" of JS (the one that centers the stack of images), but I can't think of it for the life of me.